# Laravel and AngularJS Routing Issue

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angular-ui-router

I've got a small issue with routing with AngularJS using Laravel. When I have a url like `www.example.com/blog` and I refresh, it will load fine under the AngularJS UI Router, however, when I have `www.example.com/blog/1` and I refresh it shows the Laravel-side 404.

I have my `web.php` set-up like this:

```
Route::get("/", function(){
    return view("index");
});

Route::get('/{all}', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

I also have `$location.html5Mode(true);` in AngularJS and also my `<base />` and the routes are all defined accordingly.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: If you want to really catch all with the /{all} route you might want to use `Route::get('/{all}', function(){return view('index');})->where(['all' => '(.*)'])`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Great to hear! I've added a real answer to the question which you can accept for future reference and people coming here from search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference and people coming here from search results.

```
Route::get('/{all}', function(){
    return view('index');
})->where(['all' => '(.*)'])
```

A where is needed to catch all after the initial / This isn't explicitly noted in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints